# Как улучшить качество декомпозиции в Go?

Tags: golang, чистый-код

При проектировании своего кода неприлично долго думаю над тем что нужно вынеси в отдельный пакет, а что достаточно вынести в отдельную структуру. В более ООП языках (C#, да простят меня боги C++) у меня или не возникает такой проблемы, или возникает, но в меньшей степени.
Поэтому вопрос, как можно улучить навык декомпозиции в Go и в целом ? Хотелось бы услышать о курсах, ресурсах, книгах или просто ваши советы по данному вопросу.
Спасибо.

Comment: Какая разница ООП или не ООП? Декомпозиция от этого как зависит?

Comment: Такой вопрос я не поднимал, я утверждаю на основе фактов из своего опыта. Попробую ответить, ООП это инструмент которым декомпозиция творится, Golang предоставляет немного другой подход к декомпозиции, возможно зависимость в этом

Comment: Если у вас ООП, то вы делаете объект с данными, в него добавлены методы, рядом с объектом функции для работы с ним. Без ООП у вас объект без методов и функции для работы с ним. На декомпозицию это не влияет. Единица декомпозиции - данные и код для работы с этими данными.

Comment: Конкретно в вашем примере все правильно, но в Го есть такая единица как пакет, сокрытие работает только на уровне пакета, на уровне объекта сокрытия нет. Поэтому в Го абстрактный "объект" может быть как и пакетом, так и структурой. Вот у меня часто и возникает простой вопрос: "а когда то, а когда это ?"

Comment: Пакет - синглтон. Если вам нужно несколько экземпляров, это может быть только структура.

Comment: Пакет может объявлять одну структуру или несколько, если эти структуры очень тесно связаны. Вот и вся декомпозиция в Go.